# Oracle complex query with multiple joins on same table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, sql-tuning

I am dealing with a monster query ( ~800 lines ) on oracle 11, and its taking expensive resources.

The main problem here is a table `mouvement` with about ~18 million lines, on which I have like 30 left joins on this table.

```
LEFT JOIN mouvement mracct_ad1 
    ON mracct_ad1.code_portefeuille = t.code_portefeuille
    AND mracct_ad1.statut_ligne = 'PROPRE'
    AND substr(mracct_ad1.code_valeur,1,4) = 'MRAC'
    AND mracct_ad1.code_transaction = t.code_transaction
LEFT JOIN mouvement mracct_zias 
    ON mracct_zias.code_portefeuille = t.code_portefeuille
    AND mracct_zias.statut_ligne = 'PROPRE'
    AND substr(mracct_zias.code_valeur,1,4) = 'PRAC'
    AND mracct_zias.code_transaction = t.code_transaction
LEFT JOIN mouvement mracct_zixs 
    ON mracct_zias.code_portefeuille = t.code_portefeuille
    AND mracct_zias.statut_ligne = 'XROPRE'
    AND substr(mracct_zias.code_valeur,1,4) = 'MRAT'
    AND mracct_zias.code_transaction = t.code_transaction
```

is there some way so I can get rid of the left joins, (union join or example) to make the query faster and consumes less? execution plan or something?

Comment: These lines of code do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Please explain what is even remotely different between those two joins other than the alias of the mouvement table.

Comment: sorry, i updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note on performance. Usually you want to "rephrase" conditions like:

```
AND substr(mracct_ad1.code_valeur,1,4) = 'MRAC'
```

In simple words, expressions on the left side of the equality will prevent the best usage of indexes and may push the SQL optimizer toward a less than optimal plan. The database engine will end up doing more work than is really needed, and the query will be [much] slower. In extreme cases they can even decide to use a Full Table Scan. In this case you can rephrase it as:

```
AND mracct_ad1.code_valeur like 'MRAC%'
```

or:

```
AND mracct_ad1.code_valeur >= 'MRAC' AND mracct_ad1.code_valeur < 'MRAD'
```

Comment: That second one is risky, due to `NLS_SORT`, isn't it?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, I agree with you. Even though the second one is still an option, I would lean towards avoiding it, since it can be error prone when using non-typical collations.

Comment: Although a good idea, it seems highly unlikely that replacing the `substr()` with `like` would have a noticeable affect on a query with 30 left joins.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing so.  Your code sample doesn't make much sense, but you can probably do conditional aggregation:

```
left join
(select m.code_portefeuille, m.code_transaction,
        max(case when m.statut_ligne = 'PROPRE' and m.code_valeur like 'MRAC%' then ? end) as ad1,
        max(case when m.statut_ligne = 'PROPRE' and m.code_valeur like 'MRAC%' then ? end) as zia,
        . . .  -- for all the rest of the joins as well
 from mouvement m
 group by m.code_portefeuille, m.code_transaction
) m
on m.code_portefeuille = t.code_portefeuille and m.code_transaction = t.code_transaction
```

You can probably replace all 30 joins with a single join to the aggregated table.

Comment: well. its just the same join with different values.

Comment: @mouadtk . . . No, this replaces a bunch of different joins with a single join to an aggregated result.  I made the answer a bit clearer to this point.